# How to render async-component in vuejs2 with webpack2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, webpack-2, async-components

I want to render a particular component dynamically so define it as async component like this:

```
Vue.component('AsyncComponent', function (resolve) {
  require(['./components/async-component.vue'], resolve)
});
```

But getting this error

> Error: Loading chunk 0 failed.
>       at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptComplete (app.js:99)

So the major problem is that the chunk file's path is not specified any where, the throw 404 error, is there any webpack configuration also, that I need to specify.Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use a `dynamic import`:

```
const AsyncComponent = () => import ('./components/async-component.vue');
```

Then to register it globally:

```
Vue.component('AsyncComponent', AsyncComponent);
```

or simply:

```
Vue.component('AsyncComponent', () => import('./components/async-component.vue');
```

Although this will not work if you are using `vue-loader 13` or above unless you set the [esModule](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/options.html#esmodule) option to `false`. see [Release Notes](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/releases/tag/v13.0.0)

Comment: It's going to be impossible for me to debug that without knowing more about your setup. Do you have `babel` in your project to compile ES2015 and what version of `vue-loader` are you using?

Comment: this is my vuejs webpack config  `{
        test:/\.vue$/,
        exclude:/node_modules/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
          esModule: false
        }
      }`
and vue-loader version is 13.0.4 yes i do have babel

Comment: Is `babel-loader` being applied to `.js` files and are you using `babel-preset-env`?